# SQL group results as a nested array with aggregated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns me SUM amount per column for specific column 'EUR'

```
select sum(DC_SUB.REM_AMOUNT)
                       from DEBT.DEBT_CLAIM DC_SUB
                       where DC_SUB.DEBT_ID = D.DEBT_ID
                         and DC_SUB.END_DATE is null
                         and DC_SUB.CUR_CODE = 'EUR'
                         and DC_SUB.STATUS = 'ACTIVE') as REM_AMOUNT_EUR,
```

result:

```
REMAINING_AMOUNT_EUR
68837.22
```

Instead of writing query for each Currency 'USD', 'CAD', I would like to aggregate it to one column as nested array and then easily parse that values on UI.

Desired result in one column:

```
REMAINING_AMOUNT 
[['EUR', 68837.22],['USD', 1233.12], ...]
```

I approached it with group by, but it still does not return the format I want

```
select DC_SUB.CUR_CODE, sum(DC_SUB.REM_AMOUNT)
 from DEBT.DEBT_CLAIM DC_SUB
 where DC_SUB.DEBT_ID = D.DEBT_ID
   and DC_SUB.END_DATE is null
   and DC_SUB.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
 group by DC_SUB.CUR_CODE as GROUPPED_CUR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also using XML PATH variant. Constructs the pairs then aggregates them with XML.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING((  
       SELECT ',[' + DC_SUB.CUR_CODE + ',' + CAST(SUM(DC_SUB.REM_AMOUNT) AS    VARCHAR(20)) + ']'
       FROM DEBT.DEBT_CLAIM DC_SUB
       WHERE DC_SUB.DEBT_ID = D.DEBT_ID
         AND DC_SUB.END_DATE is null
         AND DC_SUB.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
       GROUP BY CUR_CODE
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 
    2,1000
) [CUR_CODEs];
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: DBMS is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable using `STUFF` function in SQLServer.

```
select top 1
CUR_CODE = 
 stuff((SELECT ',['''+ DC_SUB.CUR_CODE + ''','+ convert(varchar, sum(DC_SUB.REM_AMOUNT)) +']'
 from DEBT.DEBT_CLAIM DC_SUB
 where DC_SUB.DEBT_ID = D.DEBT_ID
   and DC_SUB.END_DATE is null
   and DC_SUB.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
 group by DC_SUB.CUR_CODE
for xml path('') 
), 1, 1,'') 
from DEBT.DEBT_CLAIM
```

Comment: when I try to select this column it says:
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. How to select it using group by clause?

Comment: if you add columns, add those also on the group by